# netctl using wrong interface

Tags: networking, arch-linux, netctl

After a recent Arch Linux update, my ethernet interface somehow got renamed from `enp4s0` to `enp5s0`, as shown by `ip link`.

After correcting this in my profile `/etc/netctl/dhcp`, and starting `sudo netctl dhcp`, nothing happens for around 30 seconds and then I get "A dependency job for netctl@dhcp.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.", which I do and get:

```
[...]systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device sys-subsystem-net-devices-enp4s0.device.
```

So it seems, netctl ignores my changes to my profile and still tries to use enp4s0. Or maybe the old name is cached somewhere in my system? How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Because I basically have the same problem now after having changed my CPU and the interfaces having different names...

Answer (score 0):

Your profile is probably called something like netctl-if[something]@enp4s0.service. So try to run:

```
$ netctl disable netctl-if[something]@enp4s0.service
```